# PostgreSQL - Recursive query with a where clause

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, how to execute a recursive query with "dynamics" clauses ?

I'm using a recursive query because my data is a hierarchical model. An object can have children, themselves can also have children...

[image: model].

My goal is to find the last children of a searched object. My recursive query use a specific value in the where clause (A in this exemple, the searched object). This values are stored in an other table (called my_table here). An other table store every relations between object (A to B, A to C, A to D, D to E, D to F...), called my_table_filiation here. I need to repeat all this recursive query for each distinct values of my_table.cadastral_reference (A, B, C, D, E, F).

In other words how can I dynamically change a clause in a recursive query and run it for every values of a distinct table ?

Tables are like this :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('my_table_id_seq'::regclass),
    cadastral_reference character varying(14) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    filiation character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",   
    CONSTRAINT my_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table_filiation
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('my_table_filiation_id_seq'::regclass),
    mother character varying(14) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    daughter character varying(14) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",   
    CONSTRAINT my_table_filiation_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Recursive query is like this :

```
WITH RECURSIVE q_filiation (mother, daughter) AS (
    SELECT mother, daughter
    FROM my_table_filiation 
    WHERE mother = 'A'  
  UNION ALL
    SELECT p.mother, p.daughter
    FROM q_filiation f, my_table_filiation p
    WHERE p.mother = f.daughter
)
SELECT
array_agg(DISTINCT mother) AS mother,
array_agg(daughter) AS last_daughter,
FROM q_filiation
```

Actual result :

```
mother | last_daughter
--------------------
{A}       | {E,F}
```

Desired results (the where clause declined with every values of my_table.cadastral_reference):

```
mother | last_daughter
--------------------
{A}       | {E,F}
{B}       | {}
{C}       | {}
{D}       | {E,F}
```

Comment: Why do you need the recursive CTE if one of the columns in the table is *mother*? Post sample data to clarify what you want.

Comment: Because a _mother_ can also have a _mother_ (or a _mother_ can have _daughters_ who can also have _daughters_...). It's a hierarchical logic. Am I clear or do I need to complete my question ?

Comment: Obviously a mother can also have a mother, but if you want for each mother all her daughters and you have 2 columns: mother and daughter then why don't you group by mother and aggregate with `array_agg()`?

Comment: Can you develop your idea ? Could your logic can find the last daughter of every mother ?

Comment: Now you mention the *last* daughter and I see that you edited your question.

Comment: Sorry for this lack of precision at the beginning, your comment made me complete my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I create a function with my previous query :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function_filiation(
    research_filiation character varying,
    OUT mother character varying,
    OUT daughter character varying)
    RETURNS SETOF record 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
rec record;
sql text;
BEGIN
sql := '
        WITH RECURSIVE q_filiation (mother, daughter) AS (
            SELECT mother, daughter
            FROM my_table_filiation 
            WHERE mother = '''||research_filiation||'''
            UNION ALL
            SELECT p.mother, p.daughter
            FROM q_filiation f, my_table_filiation p
            WHERE p.mother = f.daughter
        )
        SELECT
        array_agg(DISTINCT mother) AS mother,
        array_agg(daughter) AS last_daughter,
        FROM q_filiation
        ';

FOR rec IN EXECUTE sql    
LOOP    
mother := rec.mother;
daughter := rec.daughter;    
RETURN NEXT;
END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Now I can use it in queries :

```
SELECT 
my_function_filiation(p.cadastral_reference)
FROM my_table p;
```

If anyone know better solutions, on method or syntax, feel free to contribute.